# How do I switch betwen Python 2 and 3 when using Flycheck with flake8 in Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, flycheck

> How do I switch betwen Python 2 and 3 when using Flycheck with flake8 in Emacs?

Having installed Flycheck for Emacs, I then install a syntax-checker like `flake8`.

Installing `flake8` using `pip install flake8` makes Flycheck check Python 2 syntax.

However, using `pip3 install flake8` makes Flycheck check the syntax for Python 3.

How can I switch between the modes for Python 2 and 3 in Emacs 24?

Answer (score 2):

If you use virtual environments, either using anaconda, miniconda or virtualenv, then I recommend that you use [pyvenv.el](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv). It requires a tiny bit of configuration which I may be able to help you out with if you need but it is generally pretty easy to setup. I use it to switch between different python versions and different virtual environments.

You should also be able to simply place a variable in your [.dir-locals.el](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) file. This file sets emacs variables based on the directory that you're in. If you want to set your python-interpetter based on the project or directory that you're in you can simply create a file called .dir-locals.el in the folder with the project files that you want to edit. In that file you should then have

```
((nil . ((python-shell-interpreter . "python3"))))
```

or

```
((nil . ((python-shell-interpreter . "python"))))
```

flycheck should then switch for you. Let me know if you have any questions. Also maybe take a look at [this](https://github.com/lunaryorn/.emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/flycheck-virtualenv.el) from the creator of flycheck

Comment: Where can I find a tutorial for pyenv.el? It seems that nothing is showing up on Google. Also, what is a virtual environment used for?

Comment: The link is broken. But I don't see any tutorials or documentation anywhere, do you?